# Java Arrays and points

Tags: java, list

I have the following code which is used to sort a tree map from Point values passed from a `List<Integers>`, I assigned these values to Point then put it in the map, after sorting the map i want to assign the values in a `List<List<Integers>>` and print the points in a format like:

```
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
```

Can someone help, here is my code:

```
public class Solution {

    List<List<Integer>> nearestXsteakHouses(int totalSteakhouses, List<List<Integer>> allLocations,
        int numSteakhouses) {

    Point[] points = new Point[numSteakhouses];

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i] = new Point(allLocations.get(i).get(0), allLocations.get(i).get(1));
    }

    calculate(points, numSteakhouses);

    return allLocations;
}

private List<Integer> calculate(Point[] point, int numSteakhouses) {
    Point p = new Point();
    p.setLocation(0, 0);
    Map<Integer, Point> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 <= point.length) {
            int distanceSq = (int) point[i].distanceSq(p);
            map.put(distanceSq, point[i]);
        }
    }

    for (Entry<Integer, Point> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println((int) entry.getValue().getX() + " " + (int) entry.getValue().getY());
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution s = new Solution();
    int[] a = { -3, 0, 199 };
    List<Integer> b = new ArrayList();
    b.add(1);
    b.add(-3);
    List<Integer> c = new ArrayList();
    c.add(1);
    c.add(2);
    List<Integer> d = new ArrayList();
    d.add(1);
    d.add(4);   
     List<Integer> e = new ArrayList();
     e.add(2);
     e.add(7);
    List<List<Integer>> r = new ArrayList<>();
    r.add(b);
    r.add(c);
    r.add(d);
    r.add(e);
    List<List<Integer>> nearestXsteakHouses = s.nearestXsteakHouses(4, r, 3);
    System.out.println(nearestXsteakHouses);
}
}
```

I have managed to print the values in this format but its not what I want:

```
[[1, 2, 1, -3, 1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be lazy; use a nested for loop to print your lists instead of a simple print statement.

Comment: I don't have access to the main method it will print the returned result, so any suggestions?